# Aligning lines of text

Tags: html, css

I've got 6 lines of text in a div. Each line is in a `<li>` tag.
The text is vertically not aligned.
[image]

Is there a way to align the text vertically.

Comment: Do you mean align the dashes ? If yes you have to use a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Comment: It seems vertically aligned. Did you mean horizontally not aligned?

Comment: Ah, yes. I mean horizontally aligned. But also vertically. That the dashes are all under each other.

Comment: Where's your code? We can't debug an image. You need to put a [mcve] **in your question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<code>` tag to align the version, e.g.:

```html
<b>Serie 1:</b>
<ul>
  <li><code>1.07a</code> - <a href="#">Lijnentekening</a>;</li>
  <li><code>1.07b</code> - <a href="#">Gebouw</a>;</li>
  <li><code>1.07c</code> - <a href="#">Precisietekening</a>;</li>
  <li><code>1.07d</code> - <a href="#">Kunst</a>;</li>
  <li><code>1.07e</code> - <a href="#">Meselwerk</a>;</li>
  <li><code>1.07f</code> - <a href="#">Kozijndetail</a>;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thx, looks great.
But when I put a class in the code tag it doesn't work.
What can I do about that?

Comment: Use `<span class="code">tag</span>` with a class containing (at least) the following: `font-family: monospace;`. See https://jsfiddle.net/s2k8zt1a/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could split the `<li>text - more text</li>` element into several spans with pre-defined width such as

```
<li>
    <div style="width: 100px;display: inline-block;">text</div>
    <div style="width: 25px;display: inline-block;">-</div> 
    <div style="width: 100px;display: inline-block;">more text</div>
</li>
```

Just bear in mind there are nice solutions for this kind of thing out there such as bootstrap or something more lightweight that still provides a grid and text alignment.